# Static and dynamic routes on the same level with Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router

I'm trying to set up routing on a site (Nuxt.js) Using @nuxtjs/router to create my own router.js file.
Faced the problem of locating dynamic and static routes on the same level. I have the structure like this:

/:slug
/contacts

Opening /contacts get the wrong page with slug "contacts"

To change the structure e.g./hotels/:slug is not the way out for my situation. So..
how can i do this? Is there a way to set the priority of routes. Digging in the direction of extendRoutes did not bring any results.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: create a folder named `contacts` a file inside the folder named `index.vue`. Now create another file named `_slug.vue` in the same level as the `index.vue`.

It will be something like this:

```
--contacts
|--- _slug.vue
|--- index.vue
```

Now the route `/contacts/` will open the `index.vue` and `contacts/something` opens up `_slug.vue` with `something` as a slug.

Comment: Unfortunatelly its not a way out as i need several static routes on the same level with dynamic. For example  route "/contacts" should open one page, route "/features" another page and all the other variants after "/"  e.x "/hotel1" or "/abracadabra" should open another page - the same for all other variants - dynamic page with slug.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same issues, which didn't occur before. It happend after updating Nuxt.js a couple of minor version.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your static pages inside their own folder with their own index.vue

example:

```
_slug
    index.vue
features
    index.vue
contacts
    index.vue
```